# Read profile-specific properties programatically during runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application (v2.7.1) defines three profiles with their respective property files:

- `application-local.yml`
- `application-dev.yml`
- `application-prod.yml`

I know how to set the active profile when starting the application but does Spring also provide a way to read the profile-specific properties programatically during runtime?

The application is a shell application. When running, for example, a command like `init --stage dev`, then I'd like to use the properties from `application-dev.yml`.

Comment: There's the `@Value` annotation for that, but I mostly see it with regular `.properties` files, Also, I suspect that your configuration files have the exact same keys in all `.yml` files, correct? I'm not aware of a way to differentiate the source file for `@Value`. Is it not an option to just read the files as `.yml`. and hold them as a Bean or a singleton class?